# how can we increase the buffer size of the erlang emulator (werl on windows)

Tags: windows, erlang, emulation, elixir, elixir-iex

Please how can we increase the message buffer size of the Erlang Emulator, particularly on Windows (i.e. the WERL tool)

It seems to be limited to 999

The Same affects IEx.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to modify your question based on the fact you've already gotten one answer that isn't really what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah but this question is still valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ erl +zdbbl <your number>
```

In the doc it states that the default value is 1024 (in kb), it's weird that in werl it's 999.

You can find more info at this doc: http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html

Comment: To be clear, i'm asking about the limit of scrolled information that can be seen in the werl (or erl) console. The setting you mentioned is for **distribution buffer busy limit** are these the same?

Comment: This flag did not change anything

Comment: I understood something else from the description. Anyhow, I'm not sure that you can change that with an option. I believe you need to compile erlang with some options. I will check and come back to you!

Comment: Any luck with this please

Comment: I couldn't find anything, sorry.